# Change image, text color and background color of item in recyclerview when I press and click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have problem with this point. I want to change the image of imageview to other image and change the background item color and text color when I click on that item in recyclerview like the image below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should just handler onTouch() event for your holder.itemView and change the properties of other elements here.

Comment: if i click on item one then I click on item two how can I change image, background color and text color of item one like before i click and change the image, background color and text color of item two.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add onClickListener to holder.itemView and change as per your requirement in that listener.

You can handle that listener in onBind method.

Your code will be holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(....);

Comment: if i click on item one then I click on item two how can I change image, background color and text color of item one like before i click and change the image, background color and text color of item two

Comment: holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {
holder.image.setImageResources(....);
holder.textView.setTextColor(...);
update your view here
});

Comment: When user clicks on first item, keep a reference of first item. When user click on second time item, then check whether reference has any value, if it has value then access the view and reset that